# Convergence of a stationary iteration method for linear systems

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, fixed-point-iteration

Recently, I obtain a linear system, $Ax = b$, where $A$ is a nonsingular, strictly diagonally dominant $M$-matrix. Then I also got a matrix splitting $A = S - T$, where $S$ is also a nonsingular, strictly diagonally dominant $M$-matrix. So I establish a stationary iteration scheme as follows, 
$$Sx^{(k+1)} = Tx^{(k)} + b.$$
According to numerical results, it seems that this iterative scheme is always convergent. Is it rational from theoretical analysis? So, can we prove the convergence of this iterative scheme? i.e., 
(**we need to** show $\rho(S^{-1}T) < 1$, where $\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius.